# Leer archivo CSV menos dos últimas filas

Tags: android, kotlin

Estoy leyendo un archivo CSV en el cual quiero que me lea todas las filas menos las dos últimas. He tratado de añadir un contador para contar el número de filas, pero nada de lo que hago me funciona, a ver si me podéis echar un cable:

```
class CSVFile(private var inputStream: InputStream) {

    fun read(): MutableList<List<String>> {
        val resultList: MutableList<List<String>> = mutableListOf()
        val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
        try {
            var csvLine: String?
            var counter = 0
            while (reader.readLine().also { csvLine = it } != null) {
                counter++
                for (i in 0 until counter-2) {
                    val row = csvLine?.split(",")
                    row?.let { resultList.add(it) }
                }
            }
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            throw RuntimeException("Error in reading CSV file: $ex")
        } finally {
            try {
                inputStream.close()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                throw RuntimeException("Error while closing input stream: $e")
            }
        }
        return resultList
    }

}
```

Me estoy haciendo un lío ya que se que mas o menos tengo la idea, pero no consigo ordenarlo de tal forma que pare de contar antes de llegar a los dos últimos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lee todo el archivo y al final retorna una lista excluyendo los últimos dos elementos:

```
  var csvLine: String?
  while (reader.readLine().also { csvLine = it } != null) {

    val row = csvLine?.split(",")
    row?.let { resultList.add(it) }

  }
  // resto de código

  //retornar lista excluyendo los últimos 2 elementos       
  return if (resultList.size >= 2) resultList.subList(0, resultList.size - 2) 
         else resultList
```

Comment: Ese return no está escrito en Kotlin no? Al ponerlo al código me lo ha convertido en esto: return if (resultList.size >= 2) resultList.subList(0, resultList.size - 2) else resultList que no se si es lo mismo

Comment: Fue mi error. Ya lo corregí.

Comment: Vale, una duda ya que te tengo por aquí. Antes usaba una librería que leía el archivo directamente, no tenía que hacer el split ni nada. El problema era que a veces este archivo lo subían mal, le faltaba alguna coma y la aplicación petaba ya que la librería no era capaz de leerlo bien. Se supone que ese split añade una "," no? Por lo que este error se solucionaria.

Comment: El `split()` separa una cadena de acuerdo a un patrón dado y devuelve un arreglo. Por ejemplo: `"hola,mundo,split".split(",")` devuelve `["hola","mundo","split"]` un arreglo de tres elementos. En tu ejemplo, si una línea del csv no tiene la coma: `uno,dos tres` al usar `split(",")` devolverá `["uno","dos tres"]` un arreglo de dos elementos.

Comment: Vale, y si por ejemplo todas las cadenas son: "uno, dos, tres, cuatro," (la coma del final está ahí queriendo) y otra es sin la coma del final: en el primero devolverá: ["uno","dos","tres","cuatro",""] y el segundo lo mismo pero sin el elemento vacío del final?

Comment: Exacto. Solo por hacer mención, los espacios en blanco no se ignoran así que el resultado de tu ejemplo sería  `["uno"," dos"," tres"," cuatro",""]`

Comment: Vale, pero en definitiva no debería dar errores porque hubiera una de las filas que por ejemplo tuviera menos columnas, ¿no?  Simplemente la lista arrojaría menos valores

Comment: Correcto. Al menos en la lectura del archivo no fallaría por eso.

Comment: Pues todas las dudas resueltas entonces. Muchisimas gracias! Te marco como respuesta :)